# Click on item of customlist-view is not working

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-component

This is my code for click on a customlistview. When I click on the header, it works but after header its not working. `CustomAdapter` is another class in my App where I have defined header and all variables of listview. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.text.Html;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
      import android.widget.Toast;
      import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
      import android.widget.ListView;

         public class ProbabilityConditional extends Activity {
String htmlcodefor_root = "&#x221A", htmlcodefor_multiply = "&#xD7",
htmlcodefor_divide = "&#xF7", htmlcodefor_underroot = "&#00B3";
ListView listView1;
String htmlcodefor_space = "&#8194", htmlcodefor_pi = "&#928",
htmlcodefor_largespace = "&#8195";
String htmlcodefor_implies = "&#x21D2";
String htmlcodefor_i = "&#7522";
String htmlcodefor_angle = "&#952";
String htmlcodefor_overline = "&#x203E", htmlcodefor_plusminus = "&#177";



// TextView txtv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // txtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    // txtv.setText(Html.fromHtml("1.(constant)<sup><small>0</></> = 1"));
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    CustomAdapter.formula_one_custom_adapter_class_var =  Html.fromHtml("1  ");
    CustomAdapter.formula_two_custom_adapter_class_var = Html.fromHtml("2  ");

    CustomItemCall formula_data[] = new CustomItemCall[] {
                new                                                           CustomItemCall(CustomAdapter.formula_one_custom_adapter_class_var),
            new CustomItemCall(CustomAdapter.formula_two_custom_adapter_class_var),

    };
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, formula_data);

    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            System.out.println(position);
            Toast.makeText(ProbabilityConditional.this,position + "  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            if (position == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ProbabilityConditional.this,ProbabilityConditionalDiscrete.class));
            } if (position == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ProbabilityConditional.this,ProbabilityConditionalContinuous.class));
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your listview focusable true add these line in your xml `android:focusable="true"`
and make other item of list make false `android:focusable="false "`

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    System.out.println(position);
                    Toast.makeText(ProbabilityConditional.this,position + "  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    if (position == 1) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ProbabilityConditional.this,ProbabilityConditionalDiscrete.class));
                    } if (position == 2) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ProbabilityConditional.this,ProbabilityConditionalContinuous.class));
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . I already used that one , but its not working.

Comment: Thanks for great response. But its not working for me.... will u please give me your email ??, so that i can send total code of my aap , i think it will be help to you. Thanks again....

Comment: check your email in the code i comment this line.uncomment this before use  listView1.addHeaderView(header); in ProbabilityConditional class.and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

write code like this, simple way:-
          ListView list;
          list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
               int position, long id) 
       {
               //if in future you need to start a new activity
               //then add below line also in your activity

         Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                         startActivity(in);
                          }                                  
           });
```